# How to get the value from JSON in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to get the "formatted_address" value from this
[JSON](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=51.68742896959932,5.285915753468807&result_type=administrative_area_level_2&key=AIzaSyD0JLlSus5jTC3rwxgX1txvzROVElLCB8E) file. I'm new to this and found the documentation quite confusing. The code I have now is the following where the variable "location" is the url generated like the one above.

```
$.getJSON(location, function( data ){
  stad = data.results.formatted_address;
  console.log(stad);
 });
```

How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`results` is an array, so you need to access it as one. Given your example with only one item, you can access it directly by index:

```
var stad = data.results[0].formatted_address; // = "'s-Hertogenbosch, Netherlands"
```

If there were multiple items in the array you would need to loop through them:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.results.length; i++) {
    var stad = data.results[i].formatted_address;
    // do something with the value for each iteration here...
}
```

Comment: Thanks this worked! Looking back at it it's so obvious but all the documentation made me nuts! I'll check it as an answer in 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each(data.results,function(key,value){
     console.log(value.formatted_address); //'s-Hertogenbosch, Netherlands
 });
```